# Javascript code that reads if a link has been clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a simple bit of code (contained in a CMS and cant be edited) that and needs to be read by Javascript in the header if it has been clicked.

Here is the code

```
<div id="example" class="page-element-outer" style="text-align: left">
    <div class="page-element-inner" >
        <input type="image" name="Button1" id="Button" src="/getresource.axd?AssetID=16813" alt="Submit" style="text-align:left;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you assist?

Comment: I couldn't understand the question ! , could u add more details plz

Comment: What do you mean "reads if a link has been clicked"? Do you mean that you want a piece of JS code to run when the user clicks the link, that is, in response to the click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the element through its ID and attach a click-event listener using the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) method.

```
document.getElementById("Button").addEventListener("click", callback, true);

function callback() {
   // Do some stuff in here when clicked
   alert("clicked");

   // Return false to prevent the browser default 
   // click-behaviour, if that is desired
   return false;
}
```

**For legacy browsers**

Older versions of IE doesn't support `addEventListener`, so for those you might need to do something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("Button");
if (el.addEventListener) {
  el.addEventListener('click', callback, false); 
} else if (el.attachEvent)  {
  el.attachEvent('onclick', callback);
}
```

**Wait for the DOM to be ready**

If you plan to run this in the head of your page, you'll need to wrap it a DOM-ready event listener as well, otherwise there is a change that the click event isn't attached to the element, as that element doesn't exist in the DOM when your script is run.

Comment: Thanks for this Christofer but can you give me an expample re the DOM-ready event listener. Sorry but Javascript is not my strongest skill.

Comment: @jelly46 Would it be possible for you to add the JavaScript at the bottom of your body-element instead of within your head. In that case you wouldn't need the DOM-ready callback. The problem is that a DOM-ready callback is quite extensive if you want cross-browser support. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery).

Comment: to be honest, i dont know. I have been expressly told to put the JS in the header

Comment: @jelly46 All right, I would tell them that it would save a lot of trouble to put it at the end of the body instead, but if that doesn't bite, you would have to use something like what's being discussed in the question i linked to.

Comment: Thanks for this Christofer but it's getting too complex for me at the moment.